# se puede usar un servlet jsp con laravel?

Tags: web, jsp, mariadb, laravel-8, servlets

hace unos dias me surgio la duda de si es posible usar un servlet jsp en conjunto con laravel para ser especifico laravel 8.

Aque se debe la situación bueno es que el software esta en laravel y es un punto de venta pero ahora el cliente desea tener dentro de ese programa la funcionalidad de poder conectar lectores biometricos y basculas al programa, todo ello para poder guardar informacion en una base de datos que es mariadb y con ello manejar roles de usuario.

se que por si solo laravel no podria hacer ello y bueno si pudieran darme una pista o alguna documentacion o proyecto que los haya ayudado seria de mucha utilidad.

Comment: lavarel es php.. o sea.. me estas diciendo que php no puede renderizar una pagina que tenga en js los componentes necesarios para hacer eso?